# How to show $n=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor{\log_2\frac{2n-1}{2k-1}}\right\rfloor$ for every natural number $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, logarithms, natural-numbers, combinatorial-proofs

While answering a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063186/sum-of-set-bits-in-every-element-for-a-natural-numbers/3065281#3065281) I noticed that:

$$n=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left\lfloor{\log_2\frac{2n-1}{2k-1}}\right\rfloor}$$

for every natural number $n$.

I tried to demonstrate it using [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) (alternate form), like in the answer mentioned above, but without success.

Anyone can help?

Comment: I have posted a proof using only counting arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any way to solve this using [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) (including its alternate form) or any other similar method. Instead, this can be solved by using mathematical induction. Note that your requested formula of

$$n = 1 + \sum_{k \, = \, 1}^{n} \left\lfloor \log_{2}\cfrac{2n - 1}{2k - 1} \right\rfloor \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

works for $n = 1$ as it becomes just simply $n = 1 + \left\lfloor \log_{2}\cfrac{2 - 1}{2 - 1} \right\rfloor = 1 + 0 = 1$. Assume \eqref{eq1} works for all $n <= m$ for some natural number $m$. To prove it works for $n = m + 1$, there are $3$ specific things to note.

1. Going from $n = m$ to $n = m + 1$ involves summing one extra term,
   with the final term always being $0$ as it is $\left\lfloor
      \log_{2}\cfrac{2m + 1}{2m + 1} \right\rfloor$.
2. For each term in both summations, i.e., for $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, m$, the value is non-decreasing, i.e., $\left\lfloor
      \log_{2}\cfrac{2m + 1}{2k - 1} \right\rfloor \ge \left\lfloor
      \log_{2}\cfrac{2m - 1}{2k - 1} \right\rfloor$, since $\log_{2}$
   is an increasing function.
3. Based on the above considerations, to prove that \eqref{eq1} works,
   it's required need to show exactly one of the terms always increases by
   exactly $1$.

For any $1 \leq k \leq m$,

$$\left\lfloor \log_{2}\cfrac{2m - 1}{2k - 1} \right\rfloor = j  \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

for some integer $j \ge 0$, means

$$2^j \leq \cfrac{2m - 1}{2k - 1} \lt 2^{j + 1} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Note the "$\leq$" is only needed for $j = 0$, else it can be just "$\lt$" instead as the numerator and denominator of $\cfrac{2m - 1}{2k - 1}$ are odd integers and, thus, their division can't be an even integer. In a similar fashion, consider if for any specific $k$ gives

$$\left\lfloor \log_{2}\cfrac{2m + 1}{2k - 1} \right\rfloor = j + 1  \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

then you also have

$$2^{j + 1} \lt \cfrac{2m + 1}{2k - 1} \lt 2^{j + 2} \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

Note the increase will not be by more than $1$ since, even for $k = 1$, going from $2m - 1$ to $2m + 1$ is not sufficient for such an increase. Since $2k - 1 \gt 0$, multiplying everything in both \eqref{eq3} and \eqref{eq5} by $2k - 1$ and combining the $2$ equations through their common $2^{j + 1}$ value gives

$$2m - 1 \lt 2^{j + 1}\left(2k - 1\right) \lt 2m + 1 \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

This shows $2^{j + 1}\left(2k - 1\right)$ must be the sole even integer between the $2$ consecutive odd integers of $2m - 1$ and $2m + 1$. This even integer is $2m$, with $j + 1$ being the power of $2$ of the factorization of it and $2k - 1$ being the odd part of the integer. This confirms there always exists one, and only one, such value which will increase by $1$, as the steps are reversible. As such, this means by the inductive step that \eqref{eq1} works for $n = m + 1$ as well, thus finishing the proof by induction.

As an example, consider the case of $n = 5$ going to $n = 6$, so $2n - 1$ goes from $9$ to $11$. The value in between is $10 = 2 \times 5$. Thus, $j = 0$ here and $2k - 1 = 5$, so $k = 3$. This indicates that the $3$rd summation term, and no other, will increase by $1$, going from $0$ to $1$. First, here are the terms for $n = 5$

\begin{align}
5 & = 1 + \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{9}{1} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{9}{3} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{9}{5} \right\rfloor
+ \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{9}{7} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{9}{9} \right\rfloor \\
& = 1 + 3 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 \tag{7}\label{eq7}
\end{align}

Next, here are the terms for $n = 6$

\begin{align}
6 & = 1 + \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{11}{1} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{11}{3} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{11}{5} \right\rfloor
+ \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{11}{7} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{11}{9} \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor \log_{2} \cfrac{11}{11} \right\rfloor \\
& = 1 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 \tag{8}\label{eq8}
\end{align}

The final lines of \eqref{eq7} and \eqref{eq8} show that, as predicted, the $3$rd summation term is the only one to change, going up by $1$ from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Nice deduction and proof.

Comment: @martycohen I have posted a combinatorial proof.

Answer (score 4):

**A Combinatorial Proof:**

We are going to count the number of **even numbers** in the interval $[1,2n-1]$ in two different methods.

**Counting in method 1:**
There are exactly $n-1$ even numbers in the interval $[1,2n-1]$ namely $2,4,\ldots,2n-2$.

**Counting in method 2:** Note that every even number can be represented as $2^am$ where $a\geq1$ and $m$ is odd. Clearly **even numbers** which are less than $2n-1$ must have odd parts less than $2n-1$. Let $N_k$ denote the number of **even numbers** in the interval $[1,2n-1]$ which have odd part $2k-1$. Therefore $$n-1=\sum_{k=1}^{n}N_k\tag{1}$$ Clearly $N_k$ is the largest integer $l$ such that $2^l(2k-1)\leq2n-1$ or equivalently $$N_k=\left\lfloor\mathrm{log}_2\frac{2n-1}{2k-1}\right\rfloor$$ Therefore we get  from $(1)$, $$n-1=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor\mathrm{log}_2\frac{2n-1}{2k-1}\right\rfloor\\\implies n=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor\mathrm{log}_2\frac{2n-1}{2k-1}\right\rfloor$$